# Getting out of URL.Authority?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and c#. I have set a query string to pass the value to one page to another along with the url path. But once go to this page I will not be able to redirect to any other page.

Here is my code:

```
Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string urlString = "http://" + url.Authority + "/Projects/SearchResult.aspx/?Keywords=" + TxtSearch.Text;
Response.Redirect(urlString);
```

Here is the error:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Projects/Description.aspx/NewPost.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simply indicating the your URL in wrong - the reported url  `/Projects/Description.aspx/NewPost.aspx` anyway appears to be wrong - it should be either `/Projects/Description.aspx` or `/Projects/NewPost.aspx`.

As your code is redirecting to completely different page (`/Projects/SearchResult.aspx`), you should check that page code for above redirect/transfer.

On side note, there are couple of issues in ho you are forming the url:

1. Query-string is not passed correctly - you have used trailing slash before question-mark i.e. `/?Keywords` - you should be using `/Projects/SearchResult.aspx?Keywords=`
2. Typically, for passing to url within application, you should use `~` as application root - that way, you don't have to worry about host name & root virtual directory (if any). For example, you can write

   Response.Redirect("~/Projects/SearchResult.aspx?Keywords=" + TxtSearch.Text);

Comment: Dear Vinay C, Thank You for your answer with this i could redirect to my page and resolve the issue successfully